# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

elementary OS's [first moderator election](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close and the two new moderators are:

[image: Maccer] [image: Hasan]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking RolandiXor and Daniel Foré who will be stepping down as moderator.

Since this is a [special election with fewer than three candidates](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election), there was no voting stage.

Comment: Ahh, that explains the confusing notification: asking to vote but it having immediately ended.

Comment: @user3: Oh sorry about that. I really need to end the election a few minutes before that notification is triggered. :-(